# search for a plug-in that fixes html boxes' position

Tags: html, css, plugins, position

Is there somewhere stuck in the whole web a plug-in that helps to drag and drop boxes (div or section elements) and monitors the new position of it in the document ?
For example, here's a bit of an html document:

```
<body>
  <div id="a_box">
    <p> Hello I'm a boxy the box </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

If I apply a reset css style-sheet the position of **#a_box** is 0 for *top* and *left* (*absolute* or *relative*). Now I apply the **position** attribute to this box and I set it to *relative*.
And parse this snippet in my browser. Using this for now unfounded plug-in I can drag the box and be told of its new position regarding its position attribute and its hierarchical place in the document.
That would be a nice tool for users like me that don't use IDE to building websites.

Comment: I am not sure of a specific plugin. But I know you can do drag and drop with Jquery UI, so maybe I would start looking in that direction. http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/